# Postgresql - can't create a role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hello i'm tryng to create a datbase in a ruby on rails application but i've got this error

```
    FATAL:  role "giovanni" does not exist
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"app_angular_rails_development"}
FATAL:  role "giovanni" does not exist
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"app_angular_rails_test"}
```

It seems that there isn't a role called "giovanni" in my local computer so i tried to create one by log in in the postgresql console and insert the query for create one user:

```
sudo -u postgress -i
CREATE ROLE giovanni WITH PASSWORD 'password' CREATEDB LOGIN CREATEROLE CREATEUSER SUPERUSER;
```

but i recive this error:

> ERROR:  conflicting or redundant options

I tried to rewrite this query in some other ways following the official documentation of the database but it didn't worked

Comment: Just to confirm, did you use the exact command (sudo -u postgress -i) given above in your question ? It says **postgress** instead of 'postgres'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a user with [`createuser`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-createuser.html)  program, it has the same functionality as [`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createrole.html) (in fact, it calls this command) but can be run from the command shell.

```
$ createuser giovanni
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) y
CREATE USER
```

or with `command line` options:

```
$ createuser -P -s -e giovanni
Enter password for new role: xyzzy
Enter it again: xyzzy
CREATE ROLE giovanni PASSWORD 'xyzzy' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using CREATEUSER and CREATEROLE both. Chnage your query to `CREATE ROLE test WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';`

Answer (score 0):

This is what i usually do to set up postgres,create DB and its role to be use in database.yml on ubuntu terminal

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
##or use sudo apt-get install postgresql instead of repository
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install postgresql libpq-dev
sudo -u postgres psql
# \password
# create user blog with password 'secret';
# create database blog_production owner blog;
# \q
```

use the above role in `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production 
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: blog
  password:secret
```

once its done,you just need to run `bundle exec rake db:setup`....and you will have all the tables in your db ready.

Comment: Be carefully a repository what you suggest is [**`Deprecated`**](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql)

Comment: @Зелёный..updated my answer by adding another option apart from repository. :)